# Pandas value_counts() with multiple matches in same row

Tags: python, pandas, frequency-table

I have categorical data (`A`, `B`, etc.) in which multiple matches can exist within the same field such as `A,B`. I would like to break my data into additional rows just for the purpose of counting the number of instances of each value.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"Values" : ["A", "B", "C", "A,B"]})
df
    Values
0   A
1   B
2   C
3   A,B
```

Currently:

```py
df["Values"].value_counts()
B       1
A,B     1
A       1
C       1
Name: Values, dtype: int64
```

My ideal function would work something like this:

```py
df["Values"].value_counts(split = ",")
A    2
B    2
C    1
Name: Values, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas-series-str-split) and then [`explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html#pandas.Series.explode)

```
print( df['Values'].str.split(',').explode().value_counts() )
```

Prints:

```
A    2
B    2
C    1
Name: Values, dtype: int64
```

---

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Values" : ["A", "B", "C", "A,B"]})
print( df['Values'].str.split(',').explode().value_counts() )
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'.

Comment: @FrancisSmart I posted the full code in EDIT. Still got the error? What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: Still seem to be getting the same error version 0.24.2. I will update.

Comment: @FrancisSmart Yes, `explode()` is from version 0.25 - You're using ancient version of pandas, can you upgrade?

Answer (score 2):

Try with `stack` after `split` and `value_counts`

```
df.Values.str.split(',',expand=True).stack().value_counts()
A    2
B    2
C    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to worry about counting duplicates values on the same row [`Series.str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) + `sum`

```
df['Values'].str.get_dummies(',').sum()

A    2
B    2
C    1
dtype: int64
```